# ActiveMQ scheuler transaction logs

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I'm working with a client where we implemented a scheduled delay deliver to a queue. We then have another process that will pull from the queue and acknowledge the message.

All of this works great, but the transaction logs just keep accumulating. Even when I have zero messages on the queue I still have 11GB of transaction logs. The transaction logs are the scheduler kahadb located in scheduler/*.log.

I would think that after the message gets acknowledged that it would no longer be needed and the transaction log should get cleaned up, but this doesn't seem to be happening.

Can someone explain what I'm missing in my understanding? I've read the docs, but I still don't understand why this is happening.

Also, we are using version 5.8.0. It cannot be upgraded at the moment.

Comment: Provide more details, which transaction logs are you referring to.  Not upgrading to a version with many, many.....many fixes means you are likely not to find much help.

Comment: the transaction logs are the scheduler kahadb located in scheduler/*.log. I was no really assuming this was a bug, but maybe a misunderstanding on my part of how this should work..

Comment: No way to know from the description given, but something like this could be the issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-6152 or any number of other fixes

Comment: FWIW, ActiveMQ 5.8.0 was released in February 2013. There's been around 45 micro and minor releases since then. I understand that you say the broker can't be upgraded at the moment, but I strongly encourage you to find/make some time for an upgrade ASAP. You might even consider jumping to [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/), the next-generation broker from ActiveMQ.